# Failing to install AlphaFill using Cmake in Ubuntu

Tags: installation, cmake, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to build, install, and run some tests using the AlphaFill software. I've been following the more-or-less guide provided in the github (AF: https://github.com/PDB-REDO/alphafill) which calls for a suite of libraries and yarn. After getting all the requirements in order, I cloned the AlphaFill git repo and got the builds completed (with two warnings, but no failures).

When I go to run the install command however, I get... nothing. Not even an install error. I can't run the built alphafill command, so I know it failed somehow, or just didn't even attempt. And I'm entirely unsure why. Any ideas?

_

Here is the terminal session where I tried to build and install AlphaFill. As you can see, the build was successful, but the install, well, didn't do anything really.

For clarification, I'm on an Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, 64-bit machine. I put everything into root for ease of access. All libraries and cmake should be latest version I believe, given the very fresh installs. And yes, I did try reinstalling everything fresh and giving it another go. No dice.

```
root@vh-lab-desktop:/home/owner# cd 
root@vh-lab-desktop:~# cd alphafill/
root@vh-lab-desktop:~/alphafill# yarn
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.37s.
root@vh-lab-desktop:~/alphafill# cd build/
root@vh-lab-desktop:~/alphafill/build# cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
Using resources compiled with /usr/local/bin/mrc
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /root/alphafill/build
root@vh-lab-desktop:~/alphafill/build# cmake --build .
[  6%] Built target webpack
[ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/alphafill.dir/src/alphafill.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/alphafill.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/alphafill.dir/src/utilities.cpp.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/alphafill.dir/src/data-service.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/alphafill.dir/src/structure.cpp.o
/root/alphafill/src/structure.cpp: In function ‘json optimizeWithYasara(const string&, std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::ostream&)’:
/root/alphafill/src/structure.cpp:274:14: warning: ignoring return value of ‘ssize_t write(int, const void*, size_t)’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  274 |         write(efd, log_head.data(), log_head.size());
      |         ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/root/alphafill/src/structure.cpp:330:22: warning: ignoring return value of ‘ssize_t write(int, const void*, size_t)’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  330 |                 write(efd, buffer, r);
      |                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ 43%] Linking CXX executable alphafill
[100%] Built target alphafill
[100%] Built target mrc-depends-file_alphafill
root@vh-lab-desktop:~/alphafill/build# cmake --install .
-- Install configuration: "Release"
root@vh-lab-desktop:~/alphafill/build#
```

Comment: The project's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/PDB-REDO/alphafill/blob/trunk/CMakeLists.txt) indeed contains none `install()` commands. Not sure why they suggest to run `cmake --install .` - it installs nothing.